# Is there any accepted replacement for FlashPaper?

Tags: flashpaper

Is there any web-embeddable FlashPaper-like component to allow for the viewing of common office formats in a browser?

We're building an intranet with a lot of file listings, and if users are running through a list of files, they don't want to wait for Word to fire up to quickly view the contents of a file.  We'd like to do some pop-up model that lets users quickly view the contents of a file.

What I'm looking for, essentially, is the same functionality as the "Look Inside" feature of Amazon.

What are the options here?  I know FlashPaper was disconinuted in 2008.  Is there an accepted substitute for it?

(IE-only is actually fine, in this instance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print2Flash is a replacement :)
[www.print2flash.com](http://print2flash.com)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words is a good one, it can convert any Word document format to SWF along with its own viewer so documents can be viewed in any webpage. It works on .NET but other than that has no additional dependencies. Check out the [demo](http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.words/csharp/general/alternating-rows.aspx).